# Azure Ubuntu Linux: Why does ssh connection hang?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, ubuntu, ssh

Previously I had no problem SSHing into the Azure Ubuntu Linux, but now when I attempt to make the connection it just hangs at the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 44.33.111.222 [40.80.140.222] port 2.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file azure_keys type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file azure_keys-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
```

There is a log like the following:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 262144 byes for committing reserved memory.
```

Could it be that the insufficient memory is stopping the SSH?

Comment: @Kenster I'm seeing it as not a timeout issue? Wondering what issue this case could be related to?

Comment: You're right, I misread it. I see you're connecting to port 2. Are you sure there's an SSH server listening on port 2?

Comment: @Kenster actually port 22 but have always been using the same, and first time ever having it hang. How can I confirm? Using Azure server

Comment: Your debug trace says port 2.

Comment: @Kenster Yes but while copying over accidentally put 2 instead of 22. Same error stands though.

Comment: @JoKo Do you open port 2 on Azure NSG? I suggest you could reboot your VM or re-size your VM to larger size and try again.